# Optimized matrix operation of matrix with repeating elements in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I want to get exp() of a large matrix (A) with values that repeat at different indices. To speed-up the exp() operation I only perform it on the unique values of A and then reassemble the matrix. However the reassembly of the matrix is quite slow. The following code provides a working example:

```
% defintion of a grid
gridSp = 5:5:35*5;

X = repmat(gridSp,35,1);
Z = repmat(gridSp',1,35);

% calculation of the distances
locMat = [X(:) Z(:)];
dist=sqrt(bsxfun(@minus,locMat(:,1),locMat(:,1)').^2 +...
bsxfun(@minus,locMat(:,2),locMat(:,2)').^2); 

sizeDist = size(dist);
uniqueDist = unique(dist,'stable');
[~, Locb] = ismember(dist,uniqueDist);

nn_A = exp(1i*2*pi*rand(sizeDist(1),100));
H_A = zeros(size(nn_A));

freq = linspace(10^-3,10,100);

psdA = 4096*length(freq).*10.*4.*22.6./((1 + 6.*freq*22.6).^(5/3));

for jj=1:100 
    b = exp(-8.8*uniqueDist*sqrt((freq(jj)/15).^2 + 10^-7));
    b = b.*psdA(jj);
    A = b(Locb);
    droptol = max(A(:))*10^-10;
    if min(A(:))<droptol
        A = sparse(A);
        HH_A = ichol(A,struct('type','ict','shape','lower','droptol',droptol));
    else
        HH_A = chol(A,'lower');
    end
    H_A(:,jj) = HH_A*nn_A(:,jj);
end
```

Especially the reassembly of the matrix

```
A = b(Locb);
```

and the conversion of the matrix to sparse

```
A = sparse(A);
```

in the last for-loop take up a lot of time. Is there a quicker way to do this? Interestingly:

```
B = A + A;
```

is much faster than

```
A = b(Locb);
```

I have to perfom these operations far more often than the 100 iterations in the example.

Here a condensed version of the code up on request (below).

```
% defintion of a grid
gridSp = 5:5:28*5;

X = repmat(gridSp,35,1);
Z = repmat(gridSp',1,35);

% calculation of the distances
locMat = [X(:) Z(:)];
dist=sqrt(bsxfun(@minus,locMat(:,1),locMat(:,1)').^2 +bsxfun(@minus,locMat(:,2),locMat(:,2)').^2); 

uniqueDist = unique(dist,'stable');
[~, Locb] = ismember(dist,uniqueDist);

for jj=1:100 
    b = exp(jj.*uniqueDist);
    A = b(Locb);
end
```

Comment: hopefully someone here can provide some tips, but my initial reaction is that your matlab code is quite good, and the only way you're going to get significant performance improvement is to write a c program to do it and compile it to a mex file

Comment: Your question looks interesting. However, it seems like your code does many more things than what you say in the text. So I have two questions: are you sure the `exp`-and-reassembly is the bottleneck? And if yes, can you provide shorter code only with that part?

Comment: Yes I am sure they the reassembly is the bottleneck. The shortened code is posted in the edit of the question above. in the example exp is actually faster than the reassembly. In the original code the reassembly is faster as exp is applied over a different range of values.

Comment: I believe your algorithm may have numerical problems. `dist*sqrt((freq(jj)/15).^2 + 10^-7)` assumes values of up to 160, but `exp(-8.8*x)` suffers numerical underflow starting from values of `x` as low as 85. Resulting matrices are only sparse because of this underflow.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the dimension of dist is just 980 x 980 in which case you would be better off to just perform a dense matrix operation, i.e.

```
for jj=1:100
   A=exp(jj*dist);
end
```

which is 2 times faster than

```
for jj=1:100 
    b = exp(jj.*uniqueDist);
    A = b(Locb);
end
```

for your given example.